# Can I add an exception for a particular PID so that task does not gets killed by using taskkill

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, services

I have multiple instances of an application running on my remote server. I have created a batch file using taskkill to kill the processes. Is their a way through which I can add an exception for a particular PID so that it doesnot gets killed.

Comment: Use `if` to test the PID before calling `taskill`

Comment: @DavidPostill I dont get it can you please elaborate.

Comment: - [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Include in your question how you kill the processes.

Comment: How do you know which pid you do not want to kill?